# How can I print the most commonly occuring words in bash without using any external programming language (awk etc))

Tags: bash, shell

I want to print the most frequently occurring words in a text file in descending order, but I cant use `awk`, or `sed`, and it has to be a bash one-liner

I can print the most frequently occurring words/numbers, however I just want to print the words and not the count

```
sort inpt.txt | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 5
```

So it gives something like

```
   24 q
   13 3
    6 Y
    4 g
    3 N
```

however I just want

```
q
3
Y
g
N
```

Comment: if there is always one blank in between, you can use cut: `sort inpt.txt | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 5 | cut -d " " -f2`

Comment: `… | while read -r _ w ; do printf '%s\n' "${w}" ; done`?

Comment: @michael It likely got lost when formatting as code blocks, but `uniq -c`'s output includes a variable amount of leading spaces which make using `cut` bothersome

Comment: @Aaron If the output of `uniq -c` allows a constant space for the digits, then `cut -c 9-` could work. On my machine, it does: I always get room for 7 digits, plus one space, so the words start at character 9.

Comment: @joanis right, I was only thinking about `-f`. I think `read`-based solution will still be a bit more robust though : I'd be afraid the number of columns `uniq` uses might depend on implementation/configuration and may change with counts greater than 9999999

Comment: @Aaron I agree, the `read`/`printf` solution is more robust, although not nearly as simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cut -c <range>` to extract the text based on column numbers in the output:

```
sort inpt.txt | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 5 | cut -c 9-
```

outputs what you want on my machine.

You might have to tweak the `9-` range on your machine if it's not picking up exactly the right columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can just cut away the part you don't need

```
sort inpt.txt | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 5 | cut -b7-
```